# PleskDBException error unable to connect mysql

Tags: mysql, plesk, mysql.sock

I can't login to the Plesk control panel. I got an error. Please give me a hint about this error. My server is centos 6 installation.

```
ERROR: PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible. (Abstract.php:69)
```

Comment: I finally give my answer , the reason of this error is my disk is full and i deleted extra file from my linux , it's ok now.i saw the log of mysql.log and i give my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally give my answer , the reason of this error is my disk is full and i deleted extra file from my linux , it's ok now.i saw the log of mysql. works fine for me.